# Difficulty doing an express upgrade to 4.x

Tags: node.js, express, npm

After following the express [3 to 4 migration guide](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/migrating-4.html), I get nothing but timeouts from my app.  Silence, nothing in log output, just timeouts, leaving me no idea how to debug.

I am hoping somebody can see the mistake I made in the following.  Here's a before and after on my server and package files.  After changing package.json, I did npm install, and have started and restarted node.

package.js before...

```
"express": "~3.3.5",
```

server.js before...

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use(express.static('./public'));
app.use(express.compress());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

package.js after...

```
"express": "*",
"serve-static": "*",
"compression": "*",
"method-override": "*",
"body-parser": "*",
```

server.js after...

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(passport.initialize());

var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
var compression = require('compression');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(serveStatic('./public'));
app.use(compression);
app.use(methodOverride);
app.use(bodyParser);
```

I hope I am presenting the relevant bits here.  I am a little lost, with no errors to follow.

Comment: I don't know about your code off-hand, but i recorded a video on doing the upgrade for my projects: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjSnF45uGzU - it may help, though it is based on the same guide you used

Comment: @DerickBailey - its an excellent video.  Thanks.  Using it helped me do a better job. Sadly, I am still stopped with the same problem.

Comment: No need for `serve-static` as you can just use `express.static` which is built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is that you need to execute the middleware-generating function and pass their *return values* to `.use()` instead of the middleware-generating function itself. Examples:

```
app.use(compression());
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Any optional parameters for each middleware will depend on your needs of course, so you will want to consult the modules' documentation.

Comment: Thanks.  This must have been my problem.  After a day, I decided to build a new app with the new stuff and move my old stuff into it.  A slog, but at least I can make progress.